# How to transpose a list without Pandas

Tags: python, list, tabs, transpose, cpu-word

```
list = ['AAA\ta\n', 'BBB\tb\n', 'CCC\tc\n', 'DDD\td\n', 'EEE\te\n', 'FFF\tf']
```

Output:

```
AAA   a
BBB   b
CCC   c
DDD   d
EEE   e
FFF   f
```

I wanna transpose this list without Pandas. Like,
Desired Output:

```
AAA   BBB   CCC   DDD   EEE   FFF
 a     b     c     d     e     f
```

Comment: How and where do you output the list?

Answer (score 1):

You should start by stripping your strings of `\n` and splitting them with `\t`.
Once you have that you print your rows:

```
input_list = ['AAA\ta\n', 'BBB\tb\n', 'CCC\tc\n', 'DDD\td\n', 'EEE\te\n', 'FFF\tf']

new_list = list(map(lambda x: x.strip().split("\t"), input_list))
nb_row = len(new_list[0])
for i in range(nb_row):
    print("\t".join([x[i].rjust((max(len(y) for y in x) + len(x[i]))//2) for x in new_list]))
```

`rjust` centers the text of a "cell" in accordance to the longest text in the same column.
This is a fun exercise but your output will be messed up as soon as one of the text exceeds the length of a `\t` (prefer pandas for such tasks):

```
AAA     BBB     CCC     DDD     EEE     FFF
 a       b       c       d       e       f
```

Edit: if you want to get your output in the same format as your input:

```
output = ["\t".join([x[i].rjust((max(len(y) for y in x) + len(x[i]))//2) for x in new_list]) + "\n" for i in range(nb_row)]
```

This gives:

```
['AAA\tBBB\tCCC\tDDD\tEEE\tFFF\n', ' a\t b\t c\t d\t e\t f\n']
```